# Cannot Install RSConnect Package in RStudio on Mac

Tags: r, installation, shiny, rstudio

I am unable to install the RSConnect package in RStudio with R 3.1.2 on OS X El Capitan via:

```
install.packages('rsconnect')
```

It's telling me that:

```
package ‘rsconnect’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
package ‘rsconnect’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)
```

Is there another way to install this package? The [Shiny documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html) is a little vague on this subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `install.packages("rsconnect", type = "source")`

Comment: I did try this earlier, but there is a problem with a PKI package that cannot be compiled. This is what I see: In file included from init.c:1:
./pki.h:11:10: fatal error: 'openssl/err.h' file not found
#include <openssl/err.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [init.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘PKI’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/PKI’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘PKI’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Fixed! I did an install.packages("PKI") for that dependency and then this and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I upgraded to R3.2.4 and this problem went away. A simple install.packages("rsconnect") worked.